# CKEDITOR is not defined - Karma Angular Test

Tags: angular, karma-runner

we have a component in our application where we use CKEDITOR but the karma is not able to load the editor while running the ng test which error ''CKEDITOR is not definded ' at component.onInit(). I have tried adding types to karma.config plugins as
require('@types/ckeditor') but still no success. Is there a way to tell karma to load the ckeditor when required.

Answer (score 0):

Both CKEditor and Karma config must be available in your **package.json**.

CKEditor can be integrated into your application by adding generating the build online and adding it to the respective parent folder. It will also generate file **ckeditor.js**

Once integrated

```
import * as Editor from 'src/app/ckeditor/ckeditor';
```